# Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support my design

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have recently designed a site. But problem is in only Internet Explorer 8. Other browsers detect no problem. Problem is only on hover effect.

My `style.css` file:

```css
/*! HTML5 Boilerplate v4.3.0 | MIT License | http://h5bp.com/ */

/*
 * What follows is the result of much research on cross-browser styling.
 * Credit left inline and big thanks to Nicolas Gallagher, Jonathan Neal,
 * Kroc Camen, and the H5BP dev community and team.
 */

/* ==========================================================================
   Base styles: opinionated defaults
   ========================================================================== */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #222;
}

html {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

/*
 * Remove text-shadow in selection highlight: h5bp.com/i
 * These selection rule sets have to be separate.
 * Customize the background color to match your design.
 */

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

/*
 * A better looking default horizontal rule
 */

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Remove the gap between images, videos, audio and canvas and the bottom of
 * their containers: h5bp.com/i/440
 */

audio,
canvas,
img,
video {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*
 * Remove default fieldset styles.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Allow only vertical resizing of textareas.
 */

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Browse Happy prompt
   ========================================================================== */

.browsehappy {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */

/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Image replacement
 */

.ir {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* IE 6/7 fallback */
    *text-indent: -9999px;
}

.ir:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 150%;
}

/*
 * Hide from both screenreaders and browsers: h5bp.com/u
 */

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screenreaders: h5bp.com/v
 */

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

/*
 * Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element to be focusable
 * when navigated to via the keyboard: h5bp.com/p
 */

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

/*
 * Hide visually and from screenreaders, but maintain layout
 */

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   EXAMPLE Media Queries for Responsive Design.
   These examples override the primary ('mobile first') styles.
   Modify as content requires.
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
    /* Style adjustments for viewports that meet the condition */
}

@media print,
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles.
   Inlined to avoid required HTTP connection: h5bp.com/r
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
    * {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }

    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }

    /*
     * Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links
     */

    .ir a:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
    a[href^="#"]:after {
        content: "";
    }

    pre,
    blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    thead {
        display: table-header-group; /* h5bp.com/t */
    }

    tr,
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 0.5cm;
    }

    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }

    h2,
    h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}

/*stylesheet*/
body{
  font-size:14px; 
  line-height:18px;
  color:#fff;
  background:#C9C6C5;
}
.wrapper {

}
/*header*/

.header_area {
background: url("../img/header_bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.header_area:after {
  background: url("../img/shadows.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 13px;
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 30px 0 40px;
width: 1000px;
}
.logo,.slogan{
  float: left;
}
.logo img{width:260px;}
.main_slogan > img {
 width: 350px;
margin-left: 32px;
}
.tel {
margin-left: 280px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.tel li {
background: #535353;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
.tel span {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2b2b2b;
  padding: 6px;
}
.social {float: right;
margin-top: 21px;}
.social li {
  float: left;
}
.social li:hover {
  opacity: .6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
.social li img {
  width: 48px;
}
.header ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

/*   menu  */

.menu {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2b2b2b;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 50px;
width: 1000px;
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index:9999;
}
.menu ul li {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2b2b2b;
border-left: 1px solid #1b1a1a;
border-right: 1px solid #373636;
display: block;
float: left;
padding: 16px 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
position:relative;
}
.menu ul li:first-child{border-left:0}
.menu ul li:last-child{border-right:0}
.menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: keron;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover{background:#B70C0F; -webkit-transition: all .5s; transition: all .5s;}
/*dropdown menu*/
.menu ul ul,.menu ul ul ul{display:none;}
.menu ul li:hover>ul{display:block;}
.menu ul ul{
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
width: 170px;
}
.menu ul ul li{float:none;
border-left: 0px solid #1b1a1a;
border-right: 0px solid #373636;
border-top: 1px solid #1b1a1a;
border-bottom: 1px solid #373636;
position:relative;
}
.menu ul ul li:first-child{border-top:0}
.menu ul ul li:last-child{border-bottom:0}
.menu ul ul li:hover ul{display:block}
.menu ul ul ul{
left: 170px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
.content_box_area{background:#C9C6C5;}
.content_area {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
.image_box {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image_box {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 45px 0 0;
}
/*another source*/
.view {
   margin: 10px;
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
   cursor: default;
   background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.view .mask,.view .content {
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}

.view p {
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   font-style: italic;
   font-size: 12px;
   position: relative;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 20px 20px;
   text-align: center;
}


.view-fifth img {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.view-fifth .mask {
   background-color: rgba(146,96,91,0.3);
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -o-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-300px);
   transform: translateX(-300px);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.view-fifth h2 {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   color: #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(159, 141, 140, 0.5);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(159, 141, 140, 0.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(159, 141, 140, 0.5);
}
.view-fifth p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   color: #333;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-fifth:hover .mask {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
   -o-transform: translateX(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
   transform: translateX(0px);
}
.view-fifth:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
   -o-transform: translateX(300px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(300px);
   transform: translateX(300px);
}
.view-fifth:hover p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}
.view-seventh img {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
   transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}
.view-seventh .mask {
   background-color: rgba(77,44,35,0.5);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
   -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
   -o-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
   -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
   transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.view-seventh h2 {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -o-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-200px);
   transform: translateY(-200px);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-seventh p {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -o-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-200px);
   transform: translateY(-200px);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-seventh a.info {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -o-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-200px);
   transform: translateY(-200px);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-seventh:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg) scale(0);
   -moz-transform: rotate(720deg) scale(0);
   -o-transform: rotate(720deg) scale(0);
   -ms-transform: rotate(720deg) scale(0);
   transform: rotate(720deg) scale(0);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
}
.view-seventh:hover .mask {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
   transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.4s;
   transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.view-seventh:hover h2 {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
   transform: translateY(0px);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.7s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.7s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.7s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.7s;
   transition-delay: 0.7s;
}
.view-seventh:hover p {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
   transform: translateY(0px);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.6s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.6s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.6s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.6s;
   transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
.view-seventh:hover a.info {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
   transform: translateY(0px);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.5s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.5s;
   transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.view-eighth .mask {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
   top: -200px;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.5s;
}
.view-eighth h2 {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -o-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-200px);
   transform: translateY(-200px);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
.view-eighth p {
   color: #333;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -o-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-200px);
   transform: translateY(-200px);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.view-eighth a.info {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -o-transform: translateY(-200px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-200px);
   transform: translateY(-200px);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.view-eighth:hover .mask {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   top: 0px;
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
   transition-delay: 0s;
   -webkit-animation: bounceY 0.9s linear;
   -moz-animation: bounceY 0.9s linear;
   -ms-animation: bounceY 0.9s linear;
   animation: bounceY 0.9s linear;
}
.view-eighth:hover h2 {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
   transform: translateY(0px);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.4s;
   transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.view-eighth:hover p {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
   transform: translateY(0px);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
   transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.view-eighth:hover a.info {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
   transform: translateY(0px);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
   transition-delay: 0s;
}
@keyframes bounceY {
    0% { transform: translateY(-205px);}
    40% { transform: translateY(-100px);}
    65% { transform: translateY(-52px);}
    82% { transform: translateY(-25px);}
    92% { transform: translateY(-12px);}
    55%, 75%, 87%, 97%, 100% { transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes bounceY {
    0% { -moz-transform: translateY(-205px);}
    40% { -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);}
    65% { -moz-transform: translateY(-52px);}
    82% { -moz-transform: translateY(-25px);}
    92% { -moz-transform: translateY(-12px);}
    55%, 75%, 87%, 97%, 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceY {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-205px);}
    40% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);}
    65% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-52px);}
    82% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px);}
    92% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-12px);}
    55%, 75%, 87%, 97%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
.view-tenth img {
   -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
   -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
   -o-transform: scaleY(1);
   -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
   transform: scaleY(1);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.view-tenth .mask {
   background-color: rgba(255, 231, 179, 0.3);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
}
.view-tenth h2 {
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   background: transparent;
   margin: 20px 40px 0px 40px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   -moz-transform: scale(0);
   -o-transform: scale(0);
   -ms-transform: scale(0);
   transform: scale(0);
   color: #333;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
}
.view-tenth p {
   color: #333;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   -moz-transform: scale(0);
   -o-transform: scale(0);
   -ms-transform: scale(0);
   transform: scale(0);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.view-tenth a.info {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0);
   -moz-transform: scale(0);
   -o-transform: scale(0);
   -ms-transform: scale(0);
   transform: scale(0);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.view-tenth:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: scale(10);
   -moz-transform: scale(10);
   -o-transform: scale(10);
   -ms-transform: scale(10);
   transform: scale(10);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
}
.view-tenth:hover .mask {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}
.view-tenth:hover h2,.view-tenth:hover p,.view-tenth:hover a.info {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
   -o-transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}
    


      
/*end*/
.box {
overflow: hidden;
margin: 3px;
}
.box img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.box_part_one {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 450px;
}
.box.box1 {
  float: left;
  height: 255px;
  width: 192px;
}
.box.box2 {
  float: left;
  height: 130px;
  width: 120px;
}
.box.box3 {
  float: right;
  height: 130px;
  width: 120px;
}
.box.box4,.box.box5 {
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
.box.box5 {position:relative;
overflow:hidden;}

.comment_heading{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
display: none;
font-size: 15px;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
padding: 25px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.box.box5:hover .comment_heading{display:block;}
.box_part_two {
  float: right;
  width: 550px;
}
.box.box6 {
  float: left;
  height: 255px;
  width: 190px;
}
.box.box7 {
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
  width: 216px;
}
.box.box8 {
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
  width: 126px;
}
.box.box9 {
  float: left;
  height: 130px;
  width: 123px;
}
.box.box10 {
  float: right;
  height: 130px;
  width: 219px;
}
.box.box2:hover img,.box.box9:hover img{
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: rotateY(180deg); -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.box.box3:hover img{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.4); -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; -webkit-transform: scale(1.4); transform: scale(1.4); -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.box.box4:hover img{
-webkit-transform: scale(.8); -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; -webkit-transform: scale(.8); transform: scale(.8); -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.box.box6:hover img{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.4); -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; -webkit-transform: scale(1.4); transform: scale(1.4); -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.box.box2, .box.box2:hover img,.box.box3:hover img,.box.box4:hover img,.box.box9:hover img,.box.box5:hover .comment_heading {
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease; transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
```

my link:

http://www.mytechbd.com/demo-content

Comment: Good ol' Internet Explorar. Create a stylesheet specifically for IE8 and load that in.

Answer (score 2):

How many of your site visitors do you expect to be using IE8?

google, Facebook and a few other high volume website are only supporting the last 3 versions of vendor's browsers and redirect IE8 users to update their webbrowser version...

To provide backward compatibility for the :hover pseudoclass for IE8 you need to use a 'shim' like jquery plugins.

[web search or hover shim for IE8](http://www.bing.com/search?q=hover%20shim%20for%20IE8&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IESR02)

or provide a fallback using the onmouseover event handlers instead of the :hover pseudoclass.

[hover shim for IE8 and lower](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html)